# Get current time if cell is empty or not a valid date format

Tags: excel, vba, function

I want to get the current time but it will not get updated whenever i close or open the excel file. If the current cell where the function called out is not a valid date, then call function equal to NOW.

```
Function NowModified() As String

Dim str As String, rng As Range

str = Application.Caller.Address

Set rng = Range(str)

If rng.Value = 0 Or rng.Value = "" Then 'I tried If Not(IsDate(rng)) but still not working
NowModified = Now
Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Comment: How do you call the function? Is it a udf in Excel or a VBA function? What is `Application.Caller.Address` supposed to return?

Comment: VBA. To confirm if the current cell has some value, then if there is already a Date then do nothing.

Comment: I guess current cell is the ActiveCell?

Comment: it is when you create the function. but when youre in another cell, it will get updated in regard to the activecell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the some time stamp as a result, this is an answer:

```
Function NowModified() As String

    If ActiveCell = 0 Or ActiveCell = "" Then
        NowModified = Now
    End If

End Function
```

A **User Defined Function UDF** has some limitations. One of them is that it cannot refer to `ActiveCell`. Thus, even something as small as this will not work as UDF:

```
Function NowModified() As String    
    NowModified = ActiveCell.Address    
End Function
```

Here are the limitations:

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a function cannot do any of the following:
>
> - Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.
> - Change another cell's value.
> - Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
> - Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
> - Add names to a workbook.
> - Set properties or execute most methods.

[Description of limitations UDF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel)

Comment: it will not work this way. if the function is in A1 and then if the activecell in G77, when you save the file and close, then reopen again, the A1 will be updated relative to G77.

Comment: @HardDisk - so you are speaking about User Defined Function (UDF), I guess? The UDF cannot update other cells, except for its own.

Comment: it will update in this case because of the activecell. if you have 1000cells with this function, it will update because of activecell